# express.js API Endpoint Best Practice for CRUD

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a REST API using express.js.

My API needs to provide all endpoints to do CRUD on "users", so I have the following so far:

```
app.get('/users', getAllUsers); // get all users
app.post('/users', createUser); // create a new user
app.put('/users', updateUser); // update a user
app.delete('/users', deleteUser); // delete a user
```

But whats a good practice endpoint to get a single user?

So ideally if you GET on `/users/1234` I should only return **User with ID 1234** but if I just do `/users` I should return all users as the ID was not detected.

How can I refactor my:

`app.get('/users', getAllUsers);`

to handle both cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a higher-level router, and then call `app.use()` / `router.use()` on it.  This is the recommended approach in the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use).

```
var express     = require('express');

var app         = express();
var usersRouter = express.Router();

usersRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Got all users');
});

usersRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Got user ' + req.params.id);
});

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Comment: Best answer at my point of view, single responsibility and fragmented code to keep maintenance easier

Comment: I like this. It's the cleanest solution.

Comment: @newbreedofgeek Remember to accept the answer if it's the one that solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant , the best practice is to isolate your route operations as much as possible. There to get a single id,such route must only get that data.
Example.

```
var router = express.Router();
router.route('some/route/id/123').get(function(req,res){

console.log('id');
});
router.route('some/route/all').get(function(req,res){

console.log('all');
});
```

Comment: Does the following illustration of your question makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by providing id as an optional param and checking that in the controller function

for eg.

```
app.get('/users/:id?', getAllUsers);
```

But I'd prefer to go with single responsibility principle

```
app.get('/users', getAllUsers);
app.get('/users/:id', getUser);
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. Does this cascade down? i.e if I send in /users/123 would it skip the /users route (getAllUsers) and hit the (getUser) only. I swapped it around and in my getUser() method, if "id" is undefined I call next().. which then goes to getAllUsers()